# How to plot vectors in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, vector

I am taking a course on linear algebra and I want to visualize the vectors in action, such as vector addition, normal vector, so on.

For instance:

```
V = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])
```

In this case I want to plot 3 vectors `V1 = (1,1), M2 = (-2,2), M3 = (4,-7)`.

Then I should be able to add V1,V2 to plot a new vector V12(all together in one figure).

when I use the following code, the plot is not as intended

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])

print("vector:1")
print(M[0,:])
# print("vector:2")
# print(M[1,:])
rows,cols = M.T.shape
print(cols)

for i,l in enumerate(range(0,cols)):
    print("Iteration: {}-{}".format(i,l))
    print("vector:{}".format(i))
    print(M[i,:])
    v1 = [0,0],[M[i,0],M[i,1]]
    # v1 = [M[i,0]],[M[i,1]]
    print(v1)
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.plot(v1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot 2d math vectors with matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265234/how-to-plot-2d-math-vectors-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, each of your posts helped me a lot. 
[rbierman](http://rbierman) code was pretty straight for my question, I have modified a bit and created a function to plot vectors from given arrays. I'd love to see any suggestions to improve it further.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plotv(M):
    rows,cols = M.T.shape
    print(rows,cols)

    #Get absolute maxes for axis ranges to center origin
    #This is optional
    maxes = 1.1*np.amax(abs(M), axis = 0)
    colors = ['b','r','k']
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Vectors', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
    ax.set_title('Vector operations')

    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')

    for i,l in enumerate(range(0,cols)):
        # print(i)
        plt.axes().arrow(0,0,M[i,0],M[i,1],head_width=0.2,head_length=0.1,zorder=3)

        ax.text(M[i,0],M[i,1], str(M[i]), style='italic',
            bbox={'facecolor':'red', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':0.5})

    plt.plot(0,0,'ok') #<-- plot a black point at the origin
    # plt.axis('equal')  #<-- set the axes to the same scale
    plt.xlim([-maxes[0],maxes[0]]) #<-- set the x axis limits
    plt.ylim([-maxes[1],maxes[1]]) #<-- set the y axis limits

    plt.grid(b=True, which='major') #<-- plot grid lines
    plt.show()

r = np.random.randint(4,size=[2,2])
print(r[0,:])
print(r[1,:])
r12 = np.add(r[0,:],r[1,:])
print(r12)
plotv(np.vstack((r,r12)))
```

[Vector addition performed on random vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Asq.png)

Answer (score 76):

How about something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

V = np.array([[1,1], [-2,2], [4,-7]])
origin = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]) # origin point

plt.quiver(*origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then to add up any two vectors and plot them to the same figure, do so before you call `plt.show()`. Something like:

```
plt.quiver(*origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21)
v12 = V[0] + V[1] # adding up the 1st (red) and 2nd (blue) vectors
plt.quiver(*origin, v12[0], v12[1], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

[image]

NOTE: in Python2 use `origin[0], origin[1]` instead of `*origin`

Comment: +1 very cool, do you know if it's possible to create a legend entry for each of the arrows in the quiver?

Comment: unfortunately, no clue :/ and I am not so positive there is a way to do add individual legend for each. Perhaps something like `figtext` or `text` could do !?

Comment: absolutly you can add legend for every vector entry by adding the following into your code snippet.
`plt.quiver(*origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21, label="Name of vector")`
add this at the end of the plot
`plt.legend()`

Comment: Nice answer! What does the asterisk in front of origin do?

Comment: In Python3.5+, the asterisk unpacks a list https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480190/2839786

Comment: It would be very helpful if the axes matched the vector magnitudes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Ha, what an API. `origin` has shape (2, 3) and `V` has shape (3, 2).

Answer (score 29):

This may also be achieved using [`matplotlib.pyplot.quiver`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver), as noted in the linked answer;

```
plt.quiver([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, -2, 4], [1, 2, -7], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image: mpl output]

Comment: +1 for proper scale definition (as advised in the [quiver documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html), under `scale_units`), instead of using `scale = 21` as in the accepted answer which feels like hardcoding

Answer (score 10):

Your main problem is you create new figures in your loop, so each vector gets drawn on a different figure. Here's what I came up with, let me know if it's still not what you expect:

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])

rows,cols = M.T.shape

#Get absolute maxes for axis ranges to center origin
#This is optional
maxes = 1.1*np.amax(abs(M), axis = 0)

for i,l in enumerate(range(0,cols)):
    xs = [0,M[i,0]]
    ys = [0,M[i,1]]
    plt.plot(xs,ys)

plt.plot(0,0,'ok') #<-- plot a black point at the origin
plt.axis('equal')  #<-- set the axes to the same scale
plt.xlim([-maxes[0],maxes[0]]) #<-- set the x axis limits
plt.ylim([-maxes[1],maxes[1]]) #<-- set the y axis limits
plt.legend(['V'+str(i+1) for i in range(cols)]) #<-- give a legend
plt.grid(b=True, which='major') #<-- plot grid lines
plt.show()
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

EDIT CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])

rows,cols = M.T.shape

#Get absolute maxes for axis ranges to center origin
#This is optional
maxes = 1.1*np.amax(abs(M), axis = 0)
colors = ['b','r','k']


for i,l in enumerate(range(0,cols)):
    plt.axes().arrow(0,0,M[i,0],M[i,1],head_width=0.05,head_length=0.1,color = colors[i])

plt.plot(0,0,'ok') #<-- plot a black point at the origin
plt.axis('equal')  #<-- set the axes to the same scale
plt.xlim([-maxes[0],maxes[0]]) #<-- set the x axis limits
plt.ylim([-maxes[1],maxes[1]]) #<-- set the y axis limits
plt.grid(b=True, which='major') #<-- plot grid lines
plt.show()
```

EDIT OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: That looks pretty cool, can we have arrow heads for each vector.

Comment: Yes definitely! Personally I think the dot at the origin is enough to give directionality, but you can steal some commands from what juanpa has in his answer. I tried playing with arrows but struggled getting them to be different entries in the legend and fit on screen (see update)

Comment: Hey Thank you, I have commented out the plt.axis('equal'). Now Its showing all the vectors with specified x,y limits.

Comment: Maybe a little update: For me, with Matplotlib 3.4.1, your edited answer should leave out the .axes() when plotting the arrows, eg. `plt.arrow(0,0,M[i,0],M[i,1],head_width=0.3,head_length=0.3,color = colors[i], length_includes_head=True)`

Answer (score 7):

What did you expect the following to do?

```
v1 = [0,0],[M[i,0],M[i,1]]
v1 = [M[i,0]],[M[i,1]]
```

This is making two different tuples, and you overwrite what you did the first time... Anyway, `matplotlib` does not understand what a "vector" is in the sense you are using. You have to be explicit, and plot "arrows":

```
In [5]: ax = plt.axes()

In [6]: ax.arrow(0, 0, *v1, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1)
Out[6]: <matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow at 0x114fc8358>

In [7]: ax.arrow(0, 0, *v2, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1)
Out[7]: <matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow at 0x115bb1470>

In [8]: plt.ylim(-5,5)
Out[8]: (-5, 5)

In [9]: plt.xlim(-5,5)
Out[9]: (-5, 5)

In [10]: plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the extra line of v1.

Comment: I was testing all the possibilities, finally decided to ask the community, while doing so I didn't remove that line. what all I wanted is to plot a vector as we draw in our notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

All nice solutions, borrowing and improvising for special case -> If you want to add a label near the arrowhead:

```py
    arr = [2,3]
    txt = “Vector X”
    ax.annotate(txt, arr)
    ax.arrow(0, 0, *arr, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to match the vector lenght and angle with the x,y coordinates of the plot, you can use to following options to plt.quiver:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2), dpi=100)
plt.quiver(0,0,250,100, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(0,250)
plt.ylim(0,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quiver is a good method once you figure out its annoying nuances,  like not plotting vectors in their original scales. To do as far as I can tell you must pass these params to quiver call as many have pointed out:  `angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1` **AND** you should set your `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` such that you get a square or near square grid. That is the only way I have gotten it to consistently plot the way I want. For instance passing a origin as *[0,0] and U, V as *[5,3] means the resulting plot should be a vector centered at 0,0 origin that goes over 5 units to the right on the x-axis and 3 units up on the y-axis.