# How to express Euclidean distance in two dimension instead of one?

Tags: python, math, euclidean-distance

I have two variables containing an array of 300-dimensional vectors called `a` and `b`. Of which the minimal value is `-10.0` and the max value is `10.0` per vector value.

My goal is to visualize *the distance in a two-dimensional space*.

## The Problem

Visualizing in one dimension is relatively easy. I take the vectors of `a` and vectors of `b`, calculate the Euclidean distance and I can visualize over one dimension. But I now want to visualize over an x-axis *and* an *y-axis*.

## Pseudo Python

```
a = [0.1, 0.343423, -2.9008, etc...]
b = [-0.3455, -6.03983, 9.098, etc...]
distance = calculateEuclidean(a, b)
print(distance) # 6.39878 | this is 1 dimension... How to make it 2?
```

Examples in any programming language are welcome :-)

PS:
My question is not about *how* to calculate the Euclidean distance (Stackoverflow is full of it) but rather how to express it in two rather than one dimension.

Comment: By definition, wouldn't you be calculating a scalar? So it can't be 2d.

Comment: Yes, that is true. No way to visualize (dare I say: hack) a scalar in a 2-dimensional space?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here but how about using the components of the displacement vector between the two points? Distance is usually just taken as the modulus of the displacement vector and hence a scalar so not really sure what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you post an example of a vector? I suppose it should be `[x1, x2, y1, y2]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281966/how-to-plot-vectors-in-python-using-matplotlib

Comment: I've updated the question to be a bit more precise.

Comment: The question really isn't clear. Distance is a single number. If for some reason you want to make a 2-d plot out of a set of distances, perhaps you could use the second coordinate for a different, non-euclidean distance (such as the sup-metric)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic here. It might be a good question for [datascience.se]. It seems like it might be a good fit for their `visualization` or `data-visualization` tag.

Comment: Distance is a scalar.  If you have 2D vectors when you start, you are free to plot those in 2D space.  Do you mean showing the distribution of x- and y- differences between your A and B resultant vector?  An understanding of Euclidean vectors will go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Once the eucludia distance is give by

[Formula here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

The result is always a scallar. If you want calculate for individual dimensions you should use

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
distance1 = euclidianDistance(a[0],b[0]) //first dimension
distance2 = euclidianDistance(a[1],b[1]) //second dimension
distance3 = euclidianDistance(a[0],b[0]) //third dimension
```

Comment: That makes sense, but now I only have the first two values of the array and I'll be missing the remaining 298 :)

Comment: Sorry, it's just an example. you couls add them on a list called distances like:
    for i in range (0,3): 
        distances.append(euclidianDistance(a[i],b[i]))

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do in R language
by expressing 2 vectors as matrix.

```
B = matrix(c=(2,3,4,3,8,2)
       nrow=3,
       ncol=2)
B gives you
 [,1] [,2] 
 [1,]    2    3 
 [2,]    4    3 
 [3,]    8    2

 v1 = (2,4,8)
 v2 = (3,3,2)
```

You can work with matrix standard operations
like transposing. Go deep into documentation.

**Euclidian distance**

*rdist* is from the package *fields*

`rdist(x1, x2)`

Given two matrixes it computes **distance**.

p stands for **Minkowski power**.

For Euclidian use euclidean.

`rdist(X, metric = "euclidean", p = 2L)`

`"euclidean": sqrt(sum_i((v_i - w_i)^2))`

`"minkowski": (sum_i(|v_i - w_i|^p))^{1/p}`

Comment: 1) The question isn't how to *compute* Euclidean distance (which is rather trivial in any programming language) and 2) `rdist()` isn't base R. You should mention which package you are using.