# Maintenance for matplotlib.pyplot quiver? Loss of ":" in specifying vectors

Tags: python-3.x

Long story short, the highest upvoted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281966/how-to-plot-vectors-in-python-using-matplotlib?newreg=c39158c5492d47cbb9fd98fd94a34a2d) no longer works in Google Colab, although it used to work perfectly. What exactly has changed, and how does one fix it?

Made more explicit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

V = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])
origin = [0], [0] # origin point

plt.quiver(*origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

no longer works, since it seems the capability of using ":" has been taken out of plt.quiver. The following works, however:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

V = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])
origin = [0], [0] # origin point

plt.quiver(*origin, V[0,0], V[0,1], color=['r'], scale=21)
plt.quiver(*origin, V[1,0], V[1,1], color=['g'], scale=21)
plt.quiver(*origin, V[2,0], V[2,1], color=['b'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

will do what the old code did. How can I recover the use of ":"?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the *origin part no longer works.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

V = np.array([[1,1],[-2,2],[4,-7]])
O=np.array([[0],[0],[0]])
ax=plt.quiver(O[:],O[:],V[:,0],V[:,1], color=['r','g','b'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```