# Plotting/saving multiple figures/charts with Matplotlib/Pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to achieve the following and although I think I am on the right track I am missing the last piece of the puzzle.

I am testing the performance of an algorithm and need to use combination of  configurations/parameters. I am using Python 3.8 numpy/pandas/matplotlib as well as multiprocessing.

Every time the algorithm runs it produces a result. So having input config/params as I algorithm as A result as O I can say

- run 0 = I0 -> A -> O0
- run 1 = I1 -> A -> O1
- ...
- run n = In -> A -> On

All of the n runs can be executed in parallel with multiprocessing and I am very pleased of the CPU utilization at 100% and the speddup compared to the sequential execution but...

Say I can draw a chart for each one of the run and save each on of them in a separate figure, I would expect at the end of the process n figures, each one with the data related to a specific run. What happens instead is that for some reasons the plots overlap and so

- run 0 is ok
- run 1 has what run 1 should have plus run 0 data
- run 2 has what run 2 should have plus run 0 and run 1 data

(obviously not in order as they are running in parallel but hope you get the point)

I think this happens because to plot the charts I am using the generic object available in matplotlib

```
dataframe['run n'].plot(label=params_string, title="run 1").get_figure().savefig(fig_file)
```

Although that instruction runs in the separate context of each process for some reasons it overlaps in the charts. So at the end I have n charts but the get mixed up with the data of other execution.

I am pretty sure Pandas has a way to specify in what chart you want to plot the data but I can't just find the way.

Can anybody give a hand please?

Thank you, really appreciated in advance

Comment: As you can see in the pandas.DataFrame [`plot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12265234/8345628) method, you can specify in which axes you want to plot the dataframe (via the `ax` argument). You could instance one fig/axes object for every run and then simply specify that axes for plotting. Would this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @Lith, seems like a very good suggestion, I will try it right away and let you know

Comment: Didn't really work and the annoying thing is that I am not getting any errors/exceptions. here is what I have done 
```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dataframe['run n'].plot(label=params_string, title="run 1", ax=ax)
fig.savefig(fig_file)
fig.close()
```

Comment: Hmm, weird :/  I've never used multiprocessing so I don't know what could be the problem... By the way, why using `dataframe['run n']`? Shouldn't the dataframe column be a variable? Anyways, as a last resort, perhaps you can do the plotting outside the multiprocessing part of your code.

Comment: That is also a good idea. I collect all the data from the algorithm runs so it shouldn't be hard doing it sequentially as a post-process task. It will take longer but hey... I guess if I learn how to do all of this I will post the  solution. BTW 'run n' is used as a variable, I used a string to make it clearer but probably fail in that.

Comment: I suspected that, but just in case! Hope you manage to solve the problem. I myself will have to fiddle with multiprocessing sooner than later, so yeah, post your solution if possible :)

Comment: Right I think I managed to make it work! @Lith. It was basically your solution, so credit to you for that, plus a correct implementation on my side. I will post some pseudo-code for it just to make it clearer. Thanks for the help